# XML Parsing using objective c

Tags: objective-c

I m trying to Retrieve the data from XML File into an IPhone application.

The XML File Which i used is :

```
<note>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
  <URL>http://192.168.1.75/one.png</URL>
</note>
```

In this XML I have retrieve the text but i failed to display the image from the link in the XML File.

Please Help me to Solve this Problem!!!

Comment: Please show us the code and tell us what you've tried. What are the error messages?

Answer (score 0):

So your looking to load the URL into an image?

This should do the trick. (Untested code btw.)

```
NSURL *url;
NSData *data;
UIImage *image;

url = [NSURL URLWithString:xmlURL];
data = [[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url] autorelease];
image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

// do something with the image
```